# Pagination does not change the items on different pages

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I added pagination in my application. The same results are displayed on each page and according to the URL, the pages are definitely changing. I've tried a ton of solutions but none worked. Please help me find what I did wrong

My Controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {   
       
        $competitions = Competition::latest()->paginate(1);
    
        return view('competition.index', compact('competitions')); 
    }
```

Inside `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider` I added `use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;` and my function looks like this:

```
 public function boot()
    {
        Paginator::useBootstrap();
    }
```

That's how I loop in view:

```
@foreach ($competitions as $competition)      
    <tbody >
       @switch($competition->status)
            @case('active')
                <tr>
            @break

            @case('to_push')
                <tr class="bg-secondary">
            @break

            @case('inactive')
                <tr class="bg-warning">
            @break

            @default
                <tr>
            @endswitch
            <td>{{ $competition->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $competition->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $competition->status }}</td>
            <td>{{ $competition->mode }}</td>
            <td>{{ $competition->type }}</td>
            <td>{{ $competition->frequency }}</td>
            <td>{{ $competition->last_push }}</td>
            <td>{{ $competition->next_push }}</td>
            <td class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="{{ route('events.list_by_competition',['competition' => $competition->id]) }}">Events</a></td>   
            <td class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="{{ route('competitions.exports',$competition->id) }}">Exports</a></td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <form action="{{ route('competitions.destroy',$competition->id) }}" method="POST">
    
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="{{ route('competitions.edit',$competition->id) }}">Edit</a>
   
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
      
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
                </form>
            </td>
    
        </tr>
 </tbody>
        @endforeach
    </table>
    {{  $competitions->links() }}
```

Comment: your code seems right. can you share the sample URL which is being generated and its results? and are you getting pagination numbers right according to total results? also what happens if you paginate 10 items instead of 1?

Comment: @UmarSharjeel It will display 10 items but since I've got only 4 I am working with that (: And yes the numbers are correct 4 items, 1 per page it displays 4 pages in total. The URL   `http://ioc.enet.local:8003/competitions?page=2` and it changes from 1 to 4 at the end. Thats how I know the pages are working only the items inside the table are not changing.

Comment: do you have the created_at column in the table and it has different values? it is strange why this is working like this. also check with ordering by id instead of the latest then check

Comment: Yes, I do have that column, and it's with different values. Also tried like You said `$competitions = Competition::orderBy('id')->paginate(1);` and it did not work, sadly it still displays the same result on every page

Comment: try only paginate without  latest  and check the result to find out what is problem

Comment: @Zohreh I tried only with `paginate(1)` and when I dd the results everything is correct